# Django pass data into easy_pdf

Tags: python, django, pdf

i have problem with passing data from view request into PDFTemplateView class.

Package documentation: [Django easy_pdf](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/django-easy-pdf/latest/django-easy-pdf.pdf)

My files:

---

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create_pdf/$', create_pdf, name='create_pdf'),
    url(r'^create_pdf/pdf/$', HelloPDFView.as_view())
]
```

---

views.py

currently i redirect post request into created pdf file

```
@login_required
def create_pdf(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       #handle posted data
       data = computed data
       # how to pass calculated data into test.html ???
       return redirect('pdf/')
return render(request, 'clients/create_pdf.html')


from easy_pdf.views import PDFTemplateView
class HelloPDFView(PDFTemplateView):
    template_name = 'render_pdf/test.html'
```

---

test.html

```
{% load static %}

<html>
<body>
    <img src="{% static '/some.png' %}> 
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get data from POST create_pdf view and then pass all collected data into test.html

Thank you for your attention

Comment: may be this docs help you https://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.0-dev1/api.html#module-easy_pdf.rendering

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Bear Brown:

proper view.py:

```
from easy_pdf.rendering import render_to_pdf_response

@login_required
def create_pdf(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       template_name = "test.html"
       context = dict({"name": 'ww'})
       return render_to_pdf_response(request, template_name, context)

return render(request, 'clients/create_pdf.html')
```